# Django (1.7) - data migrations

Tags: python, json, django

I have created an empty data migration script for populating one of
app db tables with data from a JSON file, using

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty <app name>
```

I want to add data contained in JSON files to the db, which at the moment consists of just one table, using a data migration script (according to Django 1.7 docs this is the recommended approach) using a custom method called `populate_db` which will use `bulk_create` to add
multiple entries to the table, and then do a `save()` to write the
changes to the db.  At the moment the custom method is empty
because I am still working on it, but the script looks like this right
now

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations

def populate_db( apps, schema_editor ):
   print ‘Populating db from JSON file...'

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

   dependencies = [
       ('<app name>', '0003_auto_20150224_2024'),
   ]

   operations = [
                          migrations.RunPython( populate_db ),
   ]
```

How do I test this script to make sure the custom method works
as expected, before I run it fully?  Can I call this from the interpreter
and test it with the db API?

At the moment if I do

```
python manage.py migrate <app name>
```

it reports there are no migrations to apply.

Comment: Is it possible you've already "applied" the migration? Check the migrations table.

Comment: I can see an entry in the `migrations` table with the name of the migration file in which I added a test line in the custom populate method.  That was on 20/03.

Answer (score 10):

You can migrate backward:

```
python migrate <app name> 0003
```

And then run your migration again:

```
python migrate <app name>
```

**UPDATE**: To make the data migration reversible add the [`reverse_code`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) argument:

```
def depopulate_db(apps, schema_editor):
    print 'Deleting previously added data from db...'

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    ...
    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(populate_db, depopulate_db),
    ]
```

Comment: Did not work, it said the name of the latest migration (prefixed with `0004` is not reversible) and this latest migration seems already to have been done (an entry appears in the `migrations` table).

Comment: I tried what you write but I'm not able to do the rollback. The strange thing is this:

I have 2 runpython. One load data from fixture anche the other perform creates.

When I do the delete for records created with create, they are found and deleted. But when I query the DB for the records created with fixture, they doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution that works: manually deleting the entry in the `migrations` db table for the migration I want do undo, and then running the migration again using `python manage.py migrate <migration>`.

Maybe not the recommended approach but it appears to work, because the test output I added as a filler for the custom method in the migration file is displayed.

Maybe the Django people could think about adding a `undo_migrate` option with `manage.py`.